# Switch between languages in content editor programmatically in sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I want to switch between languages in content editor programmatically after saving item in sitecore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve the desired result is to add a processor to the `saveUI` pipeline, that will reference `ContentEditorDataContext` and will change its language. To do so, we need to create a class with `Process` method like so:

```
public class LanguageChangeAfterSave
{
    public void Process(Sitecore.Pipelines.Save.SaveArgs args)
    {
        var contentEditorDataContext = Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.FindControl("ContentEditorDataContext") as Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.DataContext;
        contentEditorDataContext.Language = Language.Parse("en");
        contentEditorDataContext.Refresh();
    }
}
```

And in order to add this pipeline processor to the saveUI pipeline, we also create a .config file with the following content, and drop it to the webroot\App_Config\Include\ dirctory:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <processors>
            <saveUI>
                <processor type="YourNamespace.LanguageChangeAfterSave,YourAssembly" />
            </saveUI>
        </processors>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```